# Laravel eloquent dynamic query with where 1

Tags: laravel

I am building a dynamic query in eloquent. i matching patterns if pattern doesnt match then i want `WHERE 1`. Basically my question is how to write `WHERE 1` in eloquent

```
if (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {

  $filter="'email','{$request->input('user_search')}'";

} elseif (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {
  
  $filter="'mobile','{$request->input('user_search')}'";

} elseif (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {
  
  $filter="'name','like','%{$request->input('user_search')}%'";

} else {
  $filter=' I want WHERE 1 here';
  The question how to write WHERE 1
}

$user = User::where($filter)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(50);
```

Comment: why do you need `WHERE 1`?  and what version of Laravel and PHP are you using? also all those "filters" are strings, the `where` method works on columns and values

Comment: I want if no conditions matches then its return all record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to define what is passed to `where` in one statement and not using multiple variables for the arguments, you can use an array:

```
if (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {
    $filter = [['email', $request->input('user_search')]];
} elseif (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {
    $filter = [['mobile', $request->input('user_search')]];
} elseif (preg_match('/pattern/', $request->input('user_search'))) {
    $filter = [['name', 'like', '%'. $request->input('user_search') .'%']];
} else {
    $filter = [];
}

$users = User::where($filter)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(50);
```

If you pass an empty array to `where` it does not add a `WHERE` condition.